# c++ fff mock temporary disable fake function

Tags: c++, mocking

I have the following code :

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "fff.h"
#include <sys/mman.h>
DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;

FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, mmap, void*, size_t, int, int, int, __off_t);

TEST(my_test, ok) {
  FILE * pFileMmap;
  pFileMmap = tmpfile();
  int pFileMmap_fd = fileno(pFileMmap);

  void* r = mmap(nullptr,
      255,
      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
      MAP_SHARED,
      pFileMmap_fd,
      getpagesize());

  mmap_fake.return_val = r;

  void* ptr = my_function_calling_mmap();

  EXPECT_TRUE(ptr == r);
}
```

I want to mock the mmap function with a real variable returned by the real mmap.

The problem is that `void* r = mmap(...` actually call my fake mmap function...

Is there a way to disable the `fake mmap` the time to init my variable `r` and re-enbale it just after ?

Answer (score 0):

I workaround the problem by using function `dlsym` from `dlfcn.h` :

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "fff.h"
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;

FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, mmap, void*, size_t, int, int, int, __off_t);

TEST(my_test, ok) {
  FILE * pFileMmap;
  pFileMmap = tmpfile();
  int pFileMmap_fd = fileno(pFileMmap);

  // save mmap address inside fmmap to be able to use the real mmap function
  void* (*fmmap) (void*, size_t, int, int, int, __off_t) = (void* (*)(void*, size_t, int, int, int, __off_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mmap");
  void* r = fmmap(nullptr,
      255,
      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
      MAP_SHARED,
      pFileMmap_fd,
      getpagesize());

  mmap_fake.return_val = r;

  void* ptr = my_function_calling_mmap();

  EXPECT_TRUE(ptr == r);
}
```

I don't know if this is the cleanest way to that but it works.